# rubocop string interpolation and size condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop, ruby-style-guide

[image]

Before I except these two methods I wanted to see if anyone in the community had a better idea to structure these and make the cops pass.  The first one with `to_s` seems a bit crazy too.  I was thinking of refactoring the other method but that would be a single line or two.

Thoughts?

Code Examples One:

```
  def destroy(resource_name, id)
    delete "#{resource_name.to_s.pluralize}/#{id}"
  end
```

Code Examples Two:

```
  def all_products
    products_map = fetch(:products).map { |x| [x['id'], x] }.to_h
    variants = fetch :variants
    variants.group_by { |x| x['product']['resource']['id'] }.to_a.map do |product_id, product_variants|
      product.merge 'variants' => product_variants if product == products_map[product_id]
    end.compact
  end
```

Comment: Why are you using a screenshot of RuboCop's output rather than copying the text into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Code example One, maybe this can be used:

```
delete [resource_name.to_s.pluralize, id].join('/')
```

For Code example Two, yes you definitely need to refactor it.
Maybe you need to create a separate method that does all the grouping and merging, etc. for the `variants` part.
I am not sure if this is a good practice, but you can create a private method for it.